# Custom Routing is not working in Laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-5.5, laravel-blade

I need to submit a form from my blade page to a controller action. It's not working properly as of now. I have the blade view page as follows

**index.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <form action="{{route('api.api_submit')}}" method="post">
        <div class="form-group"> <label for="country">Country:</label> <input type="text"
                class="form-control" name="country" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group"> <label for="job_title">Job Title:</label> <input type="text"
                class="form-control" name="job_title" />
            </div> 
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary-outline">Submit</button>
    </form>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

And Controller as follows :

**ApiController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Contact;

class ApiController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('api.index');
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function api_submit(Request $request)
    {
        $contacts = Contact::all();
        return view('api.show', compact('contacts'));    
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

And in **routes/web.php** I have

```
<?php
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

/**
 * API routes
 */
Route::get('/api', function () {
    return view('api/index');
});

Route::get('/api/v1', 'ApiController@index');
Route::post('/api/api_submit', 'ApiController@api_submit');
```

But whenever I call `http://localhost:8000/api` it throws me error as

> Route [api.api_submit] not defined

. Why is it like that? Is there anything to do more to get that particular route to work?

I also tried to give resource route `Route::resource('api', 'ApiController');`. It also didn't work.

Attaching the screenshot below.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must name your route.

```
Route::post('/api/api_submit', 'ApiController@api_submit')->name('api.api_submit');
```

Comment: Yea I understand it just now from another question :)). Actually, there were no named routes for other Controllers post form actions. There were only resource routes. That is why I confused. Anyway Thanks >